# Help with regex c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an input string:

```
   access_token=f34b46f0f109d423sd4236af12d1bce7f10df108ec2183046b8f94641ebe&amp;expires_in=0&amp;user_id=37917395
```

Source code:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex("access_token=([^&]+)");
    MatchCollection matches;
    matches = regex.Matches(webBrowser1.SaveToString());
    if (matches.Count != 0 || access_token != string.Empty) {
        webBrowser1.IsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        if (access_token == string.Empty)
            access_token = matches[0].Value.Substring(13);
```

I get the access token but I also have to match the user_id. How can I get it?

Please help me, I'm not good at this.

Comment: You need to match `user_id` also?

Comment: does the order matter? could user_id come first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = @"access_token=f34b46f0f109d423sd4236af12d1bce7f10df108ec2183046b8f94641ebe&expires_in=0&user_id=37917395";


var result = Regex.Match(input, @"access_token=([^&]+).*?user_id=([^&]+)");

var access_token = result.Groups[1].Value;
var user_id = result.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your string is in `input` This will set the variables accessToken and userId.  If there is no match the values will be null.

```
Regex regex=new Regex("(?:access_token=(?<access>[^&]+))|(?:user_id=(?<userid>[^&]+))");
var accessToken=regex.Matches(input).OfType<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups["access"]).Where(g=>g.Success).Select(g=>g.Value).FirstOrDefault();
var userId=regex.Matches(input).OfType<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups["user_id"]).Where(g=>g.Success).Select(g=>g.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

I usually have an extension method defined to reduce typing for me

```
public static string GetGroup(this MatchCollection matches,string group name) {
    return matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[name]).Where(g=>g.Success).Select(g=>g.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This allows me to do:

```
var matches=regex.Matches(input);
var accessToken=matches.GetGroup("access");
var userId=matches.GetGroup("user_id");
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how it doesn't work, I've tested this with linqpad and your supplied string and it works fine?

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't have a reference to System.Linq so the OfType and Select extension methods failed